# Jquery - extracting and modifying text from an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some elements in my document like:

```
<div class="checkbox-inline"><label><input id="mylabel" value="False" type="checkbox">mytext</label></div>
```

When I try to get the text using:

```
$("#mylabel").text();
```

I get an error that text() is not defined on that object.  My ids are unique, so my object is in the 0: position in `$("#mylabel")` but both of these return an empty string for the text:

```
$("#mylabel").first().text();
$("#mylabel")[0].text();
```

How can I get the text `mytext` out of these elements?  And how can I programmatically modify it?

I realize now that my problem is slightly different than what I thought it was.  Please see: [Modifying the text of a label that also contains an input (checkbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280882/modifying-the-text-of-a-label-that-also-contains-an-input-checkbox) for my follow-up question. Thanks!

Comment: The way your code is structured, you can try `$('label').text()`, assuming you only have one label.  Add a selector to grab this particular label text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to access the text of the label element, in this case "mytext"? The reason this isn't working is because the id is on the input element, whcih doesn't actually contain that text

```
<input id="mylabel" value="False" type="checkbox">
```

That's the entirety of your input element.

As others have stated, you can get the value of that element using

```
$("#mylabel").val()
```

Which will give you "False"

However, if you do need the text "mytext" and don't want to change your markup you can use this

```
$("#mylabel").parent().text()
```

Which gets the element with the mylabel id, finds it's parent element (in this case the label element) and then gets the text from that element.

Now that you know that, you might realise that it's easier to just put an id on the label!

Answer (score 5):

The value of an input element is not given by `text()`, but by `val()`.

If you want to get the label text:

```
$("#mylabel").parent().text()
```

It is a bit confusing that you give the id `mylabel` to an `input` element, which is not the `label` element.

Comment: `val()` gives me `False` (the value of the input - unchecked)

Comment: @PurpleVermont what kind of `text()` are you expecting from a **checkbox**?

Comment: The label on it, i.e. `mytext` above

Comment: Oh, I think I see my problem, the text is not in the input element, it's in the label element that contains it.

Comment: Then select the parent and then the text. The text does not belong to the `input` element, but to the label.

Answer (score 0):

Its `$("#mylabel").html()` to get the inner html of tag.

EDIT:

For your particular case it can be:

```
$("#mylabel").parent().text();
```

Comment: This is for an `<input>`; it does not have any inner html. See the other answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want the **label** text.. then you want to use

`$('.checkbox-inline label').text();`

You're targeting the checkbox itself, not its' label.