# Modifying the text of a label that also contains an input (checkbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, input, label

I have some elements in my document like:

```
<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <label><input id="myinputid" value="False" type="checkbox"/>mytext</label>
</div>
```

I can access get the text using:

```
$("#myinputid").parent().text();
```

This returns `mytext` as I had hoped it would.  That is:

```
$("#myinputid").parent().text("newtext");
```

Changes my initial element to

```
<div class="checkbox-inline"><label>newtext</label></div>
```

How can I change the text part without removing the input?  Or do I have to reconstruct it?

If there's a better way to structure my checkboxes to begin with, that would be an acceptable alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Using the "for" attribute would be one option: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Using_the_for_attribute

Since the `<input>` is no longer child of the `<label>`, the input won't be affected by your changes with `text()`.

```
<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <label for="myinputid">mytext</label>
  <input id="myinputid" value="False" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

(2) Another option would be to restructure as:

```
<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <label>
    <span>mytext</span>
    <input id="myinputid" value="False" type="checkbox">
  </label>
</div>
```

Then you can change the span's text without modifying the input. A span within a label is allowed according to here: [Is <div> inside <label> block correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609554/is-div-inside-label-block-correct)

(3) Here might be a possible solution for your original HTML structure: [jQuery - setting an element's text only without removing other element (anchor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156470/jquery-setting-an-elements-text-only-without-removing-other-element-anchor)

Comment: Thanks, I chose option 2 (and put the span after the input) and used `$("myinputid").next("span")` to grab the span and change its text

Answer (score 2):

You can put your text inside an element for example a span and then use the .siblings() function instead of the .parent() function.

```
<div class="checkbox-inline">
  <label>
    <input id="myinputid" value="False" type="checkbox">
    <span>mytext</span>
  </label>
</div>

$("#myinputid").siblings().text("newtext");
```